# Does amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js support javascript v3 or AWS Kinesis Video Client SDK v3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, webrtc, aws-sdk-js, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I tried to check with AWS on Github. Issue: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js/issues/153 but, did not get a reply on it.

Based on their documentation it says, its supports AWS SDK v2.5. However, we are trying to use the new AWS Modularized SDK client-kinesis-video(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-kinesis-video/index.html) and it does not seem to work with it(getting black screen on one end but, the same code works with v2). I couldn't find a javascript v3 version of the kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js online and hence, we tried checking on Github but, there is no answer.

Would like to know whether amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js supported with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-kinesis-video/index.html